# Can I use special characters in the file name of a page?

Tags: 2011

I want to know if I can add a special character in the file name of a new page. Testing `title(arte@po?)` in Tridion I get this error:

> Invalid value for property 'FileName'. The FileName property contains not allowed characters. The only allowed characters are all except <>:"/\|?*

Is there a configuration to do in Tridion, and will it accept specific characters?

Comment: Sometimes a failed test is a good thing. Do you want at symbols and question marks in delivery? In contrast, most filename questions I get are the opposite in terms of how to limit characters (to "SEO-approved" conventions). :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is is possible to allow additional characters to be used for Directories and Filenames. However your filesystem obviously needs to allow it, and you are required to modify the Tridion System Schema.

To modify the system schema, you must edit the `cm_xml_usr.xsd` file, located inside `..\Tridion\bin\` and modify the regexp pattern inside the `name="FileName"` (or `name="Directory"`) element to allow whatever characters you want to allow:

```xml
<xsd:simpleType name="FileName">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Simple type used to restrict file names</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:maxLength value="512"/>
    <xsd:pattern value="[-a-zA-Z0-9!\(\)_~.&amp;\ ]+"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 limitations to file name in page in Tridion:

1. Characters not allowed on the target file system (no way to check on creation, only during publishing)
2. System schema, here you can configure what characters are allowed
3. Hardcoded values. You can't change those and it will be applied regardless of system schema.

So you should be able to allow @ character in system schema and if it's not forced by 2 it should work. Keep in mind that you need to restart quite a lot of services before the change will be applied